# How to use OPENSSL to sign an email message and CURL to send it?

Tags: email, curl, openssl, smime

I would like to know how to sign it with an email digital certificate and then use CURL to send this signed email message.

Below is an example of a simple TEXT/PLAIN email message that I would like to sign.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0 (Created with SublimeText 3)
Date: Fri, 01 Jan 2021 23:59:59 -0700
Message-ID: <aade2ef2-960f-4e0d-94e4-d100f5270d28@initech.com>
Subject: TPS Report #1001
From: "Michael @ Initech" <michael@initech.com>
To: "Peter @ Initech" <peter@initech.com>
User-Agent: CURL/7.75.0

Good morning.

This is a message in plain text format.

It contains no inline images or attachments.

Each line is no more than 76 characters in length.

Please reach out if you have any questions.


Thank you,

Michael Bolton
SENIOR DEVELOPER
michael@initech.com
P | 801.555.1234
```

I place the entire message in a file called `singlepart--text-plain.eml` and then I use CURL to send it.

```
curl --verbose -ssl smtps://secure.email.com:465 --login-options AUTH=PLAIN --user michael@initech.com:Letmein --mail-from michael@initech.com --mail-rcpt peter@initech.com --mail-rcpt-allowfails --upload-file singlepart--text-plain.eml
```

**Bam. That is all it takes.**

Now the following link describes how to sign mime messages with OPENSSL.

https://www.misterpki.com/openssl-smime/

```
openssl smime -sign -in singlepart--text-plain.eml -text -out signed-singlepart--text-plain.eml -signer michael-digital-signature.pem
```

RFC 8551 Section 3.5, 3.5.1 & 3.5.2 shows limited examples on how to structure the message and my question is how to correctly do this.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8551#section-3.5

What I don't know is, what am I signing?
The entire content?
Just the literal body of the message?
Is this supposed to be a multipart message containing the body of text unchanged and a digital signature as a base64 attachment?

Or is it supposed to contain modified/signed text within a single part just like text/plain?

As you know, RFC documents are not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the message body is signed. That is everything after the blank line that comes after the headers.

Headers cannot be included because they can be changed (existing ones modified, or new ones added) by mail servers and mail clients on their way to the recipient.

However, there are approaches to include some important headers (like `To` and `Subject`) by copying them to the body, but they're not widely supported (yet?).

`openssl smime` knows how to handle the S/MIME message correctly, so its input is the complete message (`singlepart--text-plain.eml` in your example).

---

Here's a load of useful `openssl smime` examples which I've copied from the page http://openssl.cs.utah.edu/docs/apps/smime.html which, much to my regret, seems to be gone:

Create a cleartext signed message:

```
openssl smime -sign -in message.txt -text -out mail.msg \
    -signer mycert.pem
```

Create an opaque signed message:

```
openssl smime -sign -in message.txt -text -out mail.msg -nodetach \
    -signer mycert.pem
```

Create a signed message, include some additional certificates and read the private key from another file:

```
openssl smime -sign -in in.txt -text -out mail.msg \
    -signer mycert.pem -inkey mykey.pem -certfile mycerts.pem
```

Create a signed message with two signers:

```
openssl smime -sign -in message.txt -text -out mail.msg \
    -signer mycert.pem -signer othercert.pem
```

Send a signed message under Unix directly to sendmail, including headers:

```
openssl smime -sign -in in.txt -text -signer mycert.pem \
    -from steve@openssl.org -to someone@somewhere \
    -subject "Signed message" | sendmail someone@somewhere
```

Verify a message and extract the signer's certificate if successful:

```
openssl smime -verify -in mail.msg -signer user.pem -out signedtext.txt
```

Send encrypted mail using triple DES:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in in.txt -from steve@openssl.org \
    -to someone@somewhere -subject "Encrypted message" \
    -des3 user.pem -out mail.msg
```

Sign and encrypt mail:

```
openssl smime -sign -in ml.txt -signer my.pem -text \
    | openssl smime -encrypt -out mail.msg \
    -from steve@openssl.org -to someone@somewhere \
    -subject "Signed and Encrypted message" -des3 user.pem
```

Note: the encryption command does not include the -text option because the message being encrypted already has MIME headers.

Decrypt mail:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in mail.msg -recip mycert.pem -inkey key.pem
```

The output from Netscape form signing is a PKCS#7 structure with the detached signature format. You can use this program to verify the signature by line wrapping the base64 encoded structure and surrounding it with:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
-----END PKCS7-----
```

and using the command:

```
 openssl smime -verify -inform PEM -in signature.pem -content content.txt
```

Alternatively you can base64 decode the signature and use:

```
openssl smime -verify -inform DER -in signature.der -content content.txt
```

Create an encrypted message using 128 bit Camellia:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in plain.txt -camellia128 -out mail.msg cert.pem
```

Add a signer to an existing message:

```
 openssl smime -resign -in mail.msg -signer newsign.pem -out mail2.msg
```

Comment: Ok. So, do I feed the entire `singlepart--text-plain.eml` into OPENSSL to sign it or just the body of the message into OPENSSL to sign it?

Comment: @suchislife Sorry I seem to have misunderstood what you wanted to know. I've updated my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recap starting from the main purpose of the question.

[RFC-2311 - Section 3.4.3.3 Sample multipart/signed Message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2311#section-3.4.3.3) - I simply could not get this implementation to work with openssl. For some reason, it corrupts the message.

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed;
  protocol="application/pkcs7-signature";
  micalg=sha1; boundary=boundary42

--boundary42
Content-Type: text/plain

This is a clear-signed message.

--boundary42
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7s

ghyHhHUujhJhjH77n8HHGTrfvbnj756tbB9HG4VQpfyF467GhIGfHfYT6
4VQpfyF467GhIGfHfYT6jH77n8HHGghyHhHUujhJh756tbB9HGTrfvbnj
n8HHGTrfvhJhjH776tbB9HG4VQbnj7567GhIGfHfYT6ghyHhHUujpfyF4
7GhIGfHfYT64VQbnj756

--boundary42--
```

[RFC-2311 - Section 3.4.2 Signing Using application/pkcs7-mime and SignedData](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2311#section-3.4.2) - This implementation is veritably working in Outlook365 that I have tested.

I believe the reason `signed-data` works best is, if the entire contents are encoded to base64, it's less likely to be messed with during the email transfer process.

It takes your plain text message and embeds your digital signature into it creating an smime.p7m attachment that contains both. This is the file that contains all of it in base64 format.

S/MIME email clients will automatically verify, decode and display to you as plain text again. It works great!

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;
    name=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m

567GhIGfHfYT6ghyHhHUujpfyF4f8HHGTrfvhJhjH776tbB9HG4VQbnj7
77n8HHGT9HG4VQpfyF467GhIGfHfYT6rfvbnj756tbBghyHhHUujhJhjH
HUujhJh4VQpfyF467GhIGfHfYGTrfvbnjT6jH7756tbB9H7n8HHGghyHh
6YT64V0GhIGfHfQbnj75
```

Step 1. Generate a **Certificate Signing Request** and **Private Key** for the email address you want with openssl. Copy **Private Key** to `openssl\bin` directory.

Step 2. Use **Certificate Signing Request** to obtain a DigiCert S/MIME Class 1 Certificate (DV) from https://www.sslstore.com

Step 3. Download certificate files to disk and look for `My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle` file. Copy this file to `openssl\bin` directory.

Optional Step. Create PKCS #12 from the 3 files `My_Private.key` `My_Certificate.crt` `My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle` if you feel like importing this certificate into Windows Certificate Manager.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out My_Digital_Signature_Bundle.p12 -inkey My_Private.key -in My_Certificate.crt -certfile My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle
```

### Signing the plain text message

Step 1. Create a text file called `text-message.eml`, add the string *This is an opaque-signed message.* and copy it to `openssl\bin` directory. This file is the literal plain text message you want to sign. No headers. Just your message.

Now we are going to use the 3 files `My_Private.key` `My_Certificate.crt` `My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle` to sign a plain text message which will then be output to `signed-message.eml` file.

```
openssl smime -sign -in text-message.eml -inkey My_Private.key -signer My_Certificate.crt -certfile My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle -nodetach -text -out signed-message.eml -to "<admin@example.com>" -from "<client@example.com>" -subject "A Digitally Signed Message"
```

In the above openssl command, you see the `-nodetach` which creates a `.p7m` base64 fusion of the message and the signature into one blob.

### signed-message.eml

What used to be just `This is an opaque-signed message.` has now transformed into:

```
To: <client@example.com>
From: <admin@example.com>
Subject: A Digitally Signed Message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIISuwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIISrDCCEqgCAQExDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgEFADBKBgkq
hkiG9w0BBwGgPQQ7Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluDQoNClRoaXMgaXMg
YSBjbGVhci1zaWduZWQgbWVzc2FnZS6ggg+1MIIGTjCCBTagAwIBAgIQBK55YGZm
kBq5xX+mbFvczTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBlMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UE
ChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSQwIgYD
VQQDExtEaWdpQ2VydCBBc3N1cmVkIElEIFJvb3QgQ0EwHhcNMTMxMTA1MTIwMDAw
WhcNMjg...
```

From this point forward, the plain text message is embedded in the base64 content together with public certificates. **Even the slightest alteration to this base64 message will invalidate the entire message and fail verification**. That means nothing; no extra words, no spaces, no dots. At all. Period.

### Verify Digitally Signed Message with openssl

The final step is to verify the recently digitally signed message.

```
openssl smime -verify -in signed-message.eml -CAfile My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle -binary -signer signer-certificate-extracted.crt -out signed-content-extracted.txt
```

openssl only needs the **public** `My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle` file to do this verification. If successful, openssl will output the `signer-certificate-extracted.crt` and lastly the `signed-content-extracted.txt` that was digitally signed; the message intact, if you would.

The screenshot below illustrates a successful digital signature verification.

[image: successful_verification]

### Send digitally signed email with CURL

```
curl --verbose -ssl smtps://secure.email.com:465 --login-options AUTH=PLAIN --user admin@example.com:Letmein --mail-from admin@example.com --mail-rcpt client@example.com --mail-rcpt-allowfails --upload-file signed-message.eml
```